# Can you convert a taylor series into a power series while avoiding singularities/discontinuities that result from a=0?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

Suppose one follows the Taylor series formula for a function, defining a function as $$ \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty} \frac{f^{n}(x)|_{x=a}}{n!}(x-a)^n.$$

Then, suppose you want this function to instead be defined as a power series since that is a little bit simpler.

You might think to simply take $a=0$, except there are plenty of functions like $\ln(x)$ or $\sqrt{x}$ which don't have a derivative at $x=0$. In such a case, you'd have to pick $a$ to be something else, so how can you convert that function's Taylor series to a power series that results in just $x^n$ instead of $(x-a)^n$?

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that you can't. If I would write $$\ln(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$ then obviously I should be able to compute the derivative at $0$. $$\frac d{dx} \ln x=\frac 1x$$ This diverges at $0$. Taking the derivative of the right hand side you get $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n x^{n-1}$$ In the limit $x\to 0$ you get $a_1$, which is finite.

You might ask "but what if I just expand all the $(x-x_0)^n$ terms in the Taylor series?" What will happen is that you get for the all terms $x^n$ coefficients that can be written as $\sum_j^\infty b_j(n) x_0^j$, but there is no guarantee that these series converge.

Comment: Isn't there some way to express it as a power series but then just restrict the domain to exclude anything at or less than zero?

Comment: If the two expressions are the same for an infinite number of $x$ points, then the coefficients of $x^n$ must all be the same. I think (just a hunch) that if you write such a series it should diverge everywhere outside of the interval of convergence. But the power series converges at $0$ to $a_0$.

Comment: Okay...so how would one go about writing a power series that converges everywhere outside of some $a_0$?

Comment: @VaneVoe: I'd say you need [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) for that.

Comment: So I somehow need to take complex integrals for a purely real function in the real plane? That doesn't quite sound right.